# Short story: colonization team gets invited to a festival/ritual by natives, later found dead after sending weird messages

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi

I read this in a compilation of sci-fi stories in book form. The story starts off as a planet exploratory mission, but is told in the form of transmitted messages, with a small team on the planet and mission control inside the space ship orbiting the planet.

The exploration team encounters a primitive alien race and they have some festival/ritual and invite the team, which mission control approves. Later on the team transmits weird messages saying they should proceed with colonizing planet, and later lose the signal.

So mission control sends another team, and they discover the campsite of the first team trashed with blood everywhere. They meet up with the aliens and before mission control can say no, the second team gets invited to the same ritual. At the end of the day mission control gets the same weird messages and figure out its the aliens doing it so they quarantine the planet, or I think they bombard the planet.

I know, the way I summarize it is lame... but the story was pretty good, creepy vibes and all.

Comment: Where did you read this, and in what language? Do you remember any other stories in this compilation? When did you read it?

Comment: Forgot to say was in English and sadly no... dunno why but this story was the only one memorable

Answer (score 6):

Some elements of this are reminiscent of Joe Haldeman's [Seasons](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40494).

It has the first group of explorers who are violently killed and then a second group where the same thing happens.  I don't remember the "weird messages" but the story is told in the form of a video recording taken by the main characters.